# Разлить Pod на разные машины с Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Можно ли использовать Kubernetes как средство для разлива новых версий контейнеров.
Например, несколько десятков физических машин на которых запущено одно и тоже приложение (с разными настройками) состоящее из нескольких контейнеров. Вышли новые версии контейнеров, и надо автоматических их разлить. Подходит ли для того Kubernetes и есть ли похожий пример?